# Problems while dividing by 100

Tags: c++, c, divide

Helo, I'm new to programming and run into an issue, I have an integer, for example 158, and I divide it by 100 that i get is 1, but I want 1.58 instead

It is probably known issue, but sorry, I'm noob, for now :)

Comment: I dont know why people is answering that question, instead of saying that it is a duplicate, or helping with a comment, or saying that "does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or NOT USEFUL"...

Comment: @sebas it faster to answer, then found a dup, but agree about no research.

Comment: Sorry @ST3, you are right. I agree with you that it is faster. It is just that there are too many question without any research effort. I am a bit upset with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast this to float number

```
int i = 158;
float f = (float)i / 100;  //less precision
double d = (double)i / 100;  //more precision
//other way
int i = 158;
float f = i / 100.0;  //less precision
double d = i / 100.0;  //more precision
```

What you are doing is dividing integer from integer, in this case result always integer, to get floating point number at least one of two operand has to be floating point number.

Comment: what do you means less/more precision?

Comment: @user3408210, `double` can traditionally store more decimal places than `float`.

Comment: @user `double` type has better precision then `float` for example, `f` is not 1.58 but 1.58000004, compared with `d`, that is 1.58000001.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it will be simple.

Comment: @user3408210 google before asking, because it is really simple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide by `100.0` rather than `100`

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by an integer in C++ is always going to give you an integer, so it will never be completely accurate. That being said, it was mentioned above that you can divide by a double or long to get the accurate decimal number that you desire.